# public custom posts not showing in my wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I am building a **WordPress plugin** and I want to show all publicly registered custom post types (by theme or other plugins) in my plugin.
But it only shows **post and page** custom post types not other publicly registered custom post types like **book, movie**, and so on.

My code:

```
private function test_get_post_types()
{
    $post_types_arr =  array();

    $args = array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => true
    );

    // $post_types = get_post_types($args, 'names', 'and');
    // $post_types = array_diff($post_types, array('page', 'attachment'));
    $output = 'objects'; // Return post type objects
    $operator = 'and';

    $post_types = get_post_types($args, $output, $operator);

    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        $post_types_arr[$post_type->name] = ucfirst($post_type->name);
    }

    return $post_types_arr;
}
```

Comment: Solved it. Works fine with the solution. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414491/public-custom-posts-not-showing-in-my-wordpress-plugin?noredirect=1#comment605437_414491

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => true
);

$output = 'names'; // 'names' or 'objects' (default: 'names')
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or' (default: 'and')

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );

if ( $post_types ) { // If there are any custom public post types.

   echo '<ul>';

   foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
       echo '<li>' . $post_type . '</li>';
   }

   echo '<ul>';

}
```

Comment: I already tried it on the way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).